# Runtime error 9 (Subscript out of range) at Workbook.ActiveSheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a userform to copy values from one workbook to another.

[image]

The copying part of my VBA is this:

```
If Form.ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
    Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns("B")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("B").ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
```

I'm getting a runtime error 9: Subscript out of range at `Set targetColumn = Workbooks("B").ActiveSheet.Columns("A")`.

[image]

I'm a noob at VBA and reading up made me realize that this means that `targetColumn` isnt getting a value. I wonder why though. Whats going wrong with this?

Comment: Is the workbook called "B"? Perhaps `Workbooks("B.xlsx")...`?

Comment: @BruceWayne: That worked!

Answer (score 0):

debugging tip:

put in these lines before `Set targetColumn = Workbooks("B").ActiveSheet.Columns("A")`

```
dim aaa as object
Set aaa = Workbooks("B")
Set aaa = Workbooks("B").ActiveSheet
```

and run your code again

which one fails now?

Comment: exactly as @BruceWayne suspected .... this was just to give you an example of how to narrow down areas of failure